# Why does my 1 1/2 year old cat bite at her paws and run around frantically sometimes during the day

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

My 1 1/2 year old cat, Penny, has started to run around and bite at her back paws a little while ago. I don't know if she is in pain and I've started to worry a bit. I have noticed that before and after she runs around & bites her back paws, her back kind of twitches and she acts normal again. Does anyone have a slight clue what might be wrong?

Comment: Take her to a vet. One possibility that comes to mind is that she is having seizures. Or perhaps there's a circulation problem in her back legs.

Comment: When you say her back kind of twitches, what do you mean, is it your back side just before he/she runs off? like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7shgb4Jcyk

or is it more like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3mjd5vXsTY

the first is instinct for attacking, the second is something is irritating it's back.

Answer (score 4):

Your cat might possibly have fleas. When this happens with my cat, she will twitch her fur where a flea bites her and then tend to jump and run to avoid carpet locations where (I suspect) fleas have jumped on her in the past. The chewing of paws might be an attempt to chew a flea she has found.